# Need to have a text layer in top of a image in a bootstrap column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Bootstrap site and need to have text in a layer in top of a image that is placed in a col-md-12 column. What is the best practice to do this without loosing the responsivness?

Comment: Position that column as _relative_ and the text element as _absolute_.

Comment: Here is a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Lg3x6r0y/

Comment: Ervald, you should add your comment as answer

Comment: Thanks, it works fine but i cant mark as solved until you change your comment to answer.

Comment: must, resist, temptation, to steal @Ervald's comment as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution: jsfiddle.net/Lg3x6r0y